# SQL SELECT results INTO temp table using query string

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I am trying to write some dynamic SQL queries that select results into a temp table with a query string. It looks like follows:

```
DECLARE @SQL Varchar(4000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO #tmp_tab FROM dbo.sometable'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

It doesn't give any error to run the code, but when I want to select from `#tmp_tab`, it says the table doesn't exist.

So I am wondering if there is any special syntax for it, or dynamic SQL doesn't support such operation?

Many thanks.

Comment: your temp table exists in the scope of the dynamic SQL, not outside of it.

Comment: @Lamak Hi, thanks for your reply. Then how can I visit it from outside? I thought it is existing in tempDB, isn't it?

Comment: No, you can't, the same way that another user can't see a temp table that you create. Unless you create the temp table outside your dynamic SQL and then insert data using dynamic SQL, you won't be able to use it

Comment: Please tell us what **concrete database system** this is for - many things are vendor-specific. Are you using MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Something else entirely? Please update your tags to show what database system (and which version of it!) you're using - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it has something to do with access. If you create a global temp table, it will work.

```
DECLARE @SQL Varchar(4000)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO ##tmp_tab FROM dbo.batch'
EXEC(@SQL)

SELECT * FROM ##tmp_tab
```